# Get class object by annotation field in Java reflection or spring without bean initialization

Tags: java, spring, reflection

`Class.forname` can get the class object by name of the java class. Here, I want to give the class an alias by annotation. For example

```
@Component("foo")
class Foo {
    private String id;
}
```

How to get the Foo Class with the annotation field String "foo" in java reflection or using Spring without bean initialization?

Comment: I am a bit confused, given you are looking for a runtime annotation info, what is available in Java, afaik, is to have the class and check if there is any annotation for the class.  So your question is actually not valid: If you have a class and find out `@Component` is annotated, you already have the class.  And there is no way you can find out "class annotated with an annotation" simply by the annotation itself, unless you visit every class loaded by the classloader (which is not quite realistic)

Comment: Given you have mentioned Spring, there are quite some places in Spring that will scan classes under certain package to lookup for anntoations.  You may take a look to see its source code to see its method suit your need. (e.g. LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean)

Comment: I think the spring will get the a bean of Foo first and the get the class. However, I want to get the class directly without initialization of the bean.

Comment: Of course not.  For example, in case of Auto Component Scanning, and JPA annotation scanning in LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean, it is simply scanning for loaded classes for annotations, instead of looking at annotations of loaded beans.

Comment: Another example you can refer in Spring is : `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext`, which by digging deeper will give you `ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider`

Comment: Thank you! I will dig into them.

Comment: Another possibility that suddenly comes to my mind is a library called Scannotation.  However it have been almost 10 years ago that I last used it.  Maybe there are other better alternatives.  However I guess this serve as a starting point for you to further dig in Internet for similar libraries